How Can I Prevent A Column From Becoming Unsorted?
In AG Grid when clicking on a column header that is sortable, you are able to change it from unsorted, sorted ascending or sorted descending. I want to prevent sortable columns from becoming "unsorted" and only allow a column to become the primary sort column or change from ascending to descending. I never want the grid to be "unsorted". There doesn't appear to be any options to do this currently in AG Grid. How can I achieve this?

Of course I find the answer just after posting the question...
I just have to specify the sorting order without the default null in the gridOptions.
{
    ...
    sortingOrder: [ "asc", "desc" ],
    ....
}

